# How do I SELECT all rows WHERE from a table?

Tags: php, mysql

By the way, before it is mentioned, I am well aware I should be using mysqli. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
$q5 = "select listingid FROM userlisting WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[UserID]'";
$r5 = mysql_query($q5) or die(mysql_error());
$a5 = mysql_fetch_array($r5);
```

The userlisting table is a 'lookup' table and has two columns:
userid and listingid
It has a many to many relationship. In other words, there could be one userid attached (associated) to multiple listingids and thus having multiple rows in that table.

```
e.g.
userid|listingid
1|1
1|2
1|3
2|1
etc
```

To keep things simple: What I want to do is check the following:

```
$a5['listingid'] == $_GET['id']
```

And if it is True I will display information and if it is False the information will not be displayed.

So on the page mywebsite.com there will be an id as so, `mywebsite.com?id=[id here]`. I am trying to see if the user `$_SESSION[UserID]` has an entry in userlisting table that matches the id of the page (well, it is a property website and the id is that of the property listing).

At the moment the code I have above just searches/checks for the first row for that userid only. In the example I gave above that would be listingid ='1' It is not seeing that row 2 and 3 also have entries in them too, listingid = '2' and '3' respectively. So on `mywebsite.com?id=1` it is true, but on `?id=2` and id=3 it is coming up false, but userid = 1 has three rows with entries 1, 2 and 3.

I have been trying to find a solution for a while and I am starting to feel frustrated now. I would much appreciate it if someone could come up with a quick solution for me.

Comment: This will not create the query string you expect: `".....'$_SESSION[UserID]'"`. So dump that query string to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can check both on SQL with some clause like

```
WHERE userid=XX AND listingid=XX
```

And remember to escape the get parameter ;)

PS: You can use too a while for iterate the mysql_fetch_row and search if anyone is correct. Something like:

```
$correct_check = false;
while($a5 = mysql_fetch_array($r5)) {
    if($a5['listingid'] == $_GET['id']) $correct_check = true;
}
if($correct_check) ....
else ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$page_id = $_GET['id'];
$q5 = "select listingid FROM userlisting WHERE userid = '$_SESSION[UserID]' and listingid = '$page_id' ";
$res = mysql_qury($result);
$num_rows = $mysql_num_rows($res);

if($num_rows > 0) 
//your ok code
else
//fail message
```